# Is there any possible way to apply dynamic css on *ngFor based on following situation?

Tags: angular, angular7

Using `*ngFor`. My code is like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.content}} </td>
</div>
```

Assume data.content is "**Hello, how are you doing**". Is there any possible way to dynamically apply css on Hello to show only **Hello** in green color and others in black color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice for the letters you want in different css:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
<td>{{data.name}}</td><br/>
 <td style="color:green">{{data.content | slice:0:6}}</td> 
<td>{{data.content | slice:7:24}} </td>
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4g7vq)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of datas">
   <td>{{data.name}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="data.content.indexOf('Hello') >= 0; else elseSection;" [style.color]="red" > {{data.content}} </td>
  <ng-template #elseSection>
   <td [style.color]="black">{{data.content}} </td>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `<span style="color:green"></span>` and display the text before the `,` within it and rest of the text after the `span`

Try like this:

```
<td><span style="color:green">{{data.content.substr(0, data.content.indexOf(',')}}</span> {{data.content.substring(data.content.indexOf(',') + 1)}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I  don't have any comma and my conditions are as follows.

<li>Hello User</li> -- Have to make Hello red in color with span.
<li>Hi User</li> --- Have to make User red in color with span.

The data is dynamic and based upon a condition for some restricted keywords I need to show them with different CSS.

Comment: You can use the same approach based on your requirement and keywords